# Como inserir dados pegos de um arquivo JSON e colocar em uma lista com AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

app.js

```
(function(){

    var myApp = angular.module('loja', []);


    myApp.controller('CarrinhoController', ['$scope','$http', function($scope, $http){
        $scope.title = 'Lista de Produtos';


        $http.get('js/produtos.json').success(function(data){

            $scope.lista = data;

        });

    }]);



})();
```

produtos.json

```
[

    {nome: 'Feijao', preco: 2.95},

    {nome: 'Arroz', preco:6.58},

    {nome:'Biscoito', preco:7.60}

];
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="loja">
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Teste Angular JS</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/application/carrinho.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div ng-controller="CarrinhoController">
        <h1>{{title}}</h1>

        <div class="produtos" ng-repeat="produto in lista">
            <ul>
              <li><strong>{{produto.nome}}</strong> : {{produto.preco}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Não consigo pegar os dados dos produtos que fica em um arquivo JSON pelo `$http.get`. O erro que da no Firebug é esse:

> [ngRepeat:dupes] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.26/ngRepeat/dupes?>p0=produto%20in%20lista&p1=string%3A%20&p2=%22%20%22
>      at Error (native)

Comment: Podes criar um `fiddle` ou `plunkr` com o problema?

Comment: Tenta isolar essa parte do seu código em outro arquivo para testar, a principio está tudo ok!

Answer (score 1):

Altere o seu HTML adicionando **track by $index** em seu `ng-repeat`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="loja">
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Teste Angular JS</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/application/carrinho.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div ng-controller="CarrinhoController">
        <h1>{{title}}</h1>

        <div class="produtos" ng-repeat="produto in lista track by $index">
            <ul>
              <li><strong>{{produto.nome}}</strong> : {{produto.preco}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Na verdade o teu problema é a sintaxe incorreta do teu JSON.

Este aqui está correto:

```
[
    {"nome": "Feijao", "preco": 2.95},
    {"nome": "Arroz", "preco":6.58},
    {"nome":"Biscoito", "preco":7.60}
]
```

Aqui tem o [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Gve1nEGB2lM9KMFIaulL?p=preview) functionando.

Comment: Obrigado. Fiquei o dia todo ontem tentando resolver isso.